# How do I cache images from firebase in flutter?

Tags: flutter, caching, firebase-storage

I have been trying to do a cache management system in my flutter app. Ideally I want to retrieve images from firebase storage and display them along with other details. I retrieve the snapshots from firestore and have used cachednetworkimage to display the images. But the amount of images I display is a lot and is causing my app to crash. I believe if I was caching the image locally, that problem would be solved. And besides that, I also want to cache json files so that in offline mode, my app will display both the cached images and the other details available in the cache memory.

I want to display posts, which contain username, user profile picture, the image post itself, caption and comments. So the way I retrieve the posts is according to the following...

```
void fetchFeed() async {
auth.User currentUser = await _repository.getCurrentUser();

User user = await _repository.fetchUserDetailsById(currentUser.uid);
setState(() {
  this.currentUser = user;
});
setState(() {
  loadingPosts = true;
});
Query query =  _firestore.collection("users").doc(user.uid).collection("following").orderBy("uid").limit(perPage);
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await query.get();
for (var i = 0; i < querySnapshot.docs.length; i++) {
  followingUIDs.add(querySnapshot.docs[i].id);
}

for (var i = 0; i < followingUIDs.length; i++) {
  Query posts = _firestore.collection("users").doc(followingUIDs[i]).collection("posts").orderBy("time").limit(perUser);
  QuerySnapshot postSnapshot = await posts.get();
  lastPost = postSnapshot.docs[postSnapshot.docs.length -1];
  for (var i = 0; i < postSnapshot.docs.length; i++) {
    feedlist.add(postSnapshot.docs[i]);
  }
}
setState(() {
  loadingPosts = false;
});
```

}

And after I retrieved the posts, I put them in a listview and show them sequentially. The problem I am getting is that since the images are not cached locally, I use cached network image widget to display them. And whenever I navigate to another page and return, all the cached network images get reloaded and that puts a big load on the app, which causes it to crash.

```
 CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: list[index].data()['imgUrl'],
          placeholder: ((context, url) => Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/Black.png'),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover),
              ))),
          fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
        ),
```

Alternatively, I tried to download the images and save them locally using the following function. And I call the function for every image item I retrieve from firebase. But that just distorts the images for some reason.

```
Future <Null> downloadFile(String httpPath) async{
  final StorageReference ref = await FirebaseStorage.instance.getReferenceFromUrl(httpPath);
  final StorageFileDownloadTask downloadTask = ref.writeToFile(file);

  final int byteNumber = (await downloadTask.future).totalByteCount;

  print(byteNumber);

  setState(() => _cachedFile = file);
```

}

The http path is a download url I got for each image. But I am not sure if this is the best way to download images. Since I don't have a way to know the image file names as they appear in firebase storage, this was my only option.

Can someone tell me an alternative way to download and cache images, and also json files (which contain username, comments, caption) in my case, so that I can show them offline?

Comment: can you share your code on how you display the images or some code sample on what you tried on the described detail?

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose use [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) package. which also support placeholders and fading images in as they’re loaded.

`CachedNetworkImage( imageUrl: 'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9');`

#### Complete Example

`

```
return MaterialApp(
  title: title,
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(title),
    ),
    body: Center(
      child: CachedNetworkImage(
        placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
        imageUrl:
            'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

`

Comment: I was using Cached Network Image  but like I said it causes my app to crash as I load multiple images at once. Besides, as I retrieve the images the first time, it takes a significant amount of time to fade in the images, so basically it appears to be empty for a while.

Comment: well, you can add a [shimmer effect](https://pub.dev/packages/shimmer) while loading. and can you please edit your question and add code.